# Alternative or one word for saying re-mentioning it

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, american-english

So if I am on a group chat and I want to mention something again that I mentioned
in an earlier email to one of the people.
I could think of the following:

1. Just re-mentioning it
2. Just mentioning it again

Could there be a better way to write it? Is the above English the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to indicate that you are about to summarize briefly something that you already said, for clarity rather than for emphasis, you can use the word **recapitulate**, which means

> to repeat the main points of an explanation or description

In an informal situation like a group chat, you can abbreviate it to **recap**. For example, if you wanted to summarize the plan for the weekend that you have just discussed, you might say

> Just to **recap**, we'll meet at the restaurant at 6 on Saturday, then go to the film afterwards, and we'll meet again on Sunday morning to go for a walk, followed by lunch at a pub.

Comment: so what I understand is, if I want to emphasize something already said, I could use the word `reiterate`, and if I want to summarize, I should use `recapitulate.`

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "reiterate", so "I just want to reiterate that...".

(formal definition in Cambridge dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reiterate)

Comment: To my mind, reiterate would be appropriate if you repeated something for emphasis, but in that case you wouldn't use the word **just**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word "quote". Quoting what Mr. X said in the email above.

If you are mentioned something, you said earlier, you could say-- Repeating the point, I made above.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add “Again” at the beginning of the sentence. For example:

“I like pizza.”
…
“Again, I like pizza.”